# JMeter CA certificate issue

Tags: java, jmeter

I installed the JMeter version 2.11. When I add Http(s) test Script Recorder under Work Bench and try to record by clicking start I get an error message.  That message is:

```
Root CA Certificate : Apache jmeter TemporaryRootCA created in Jmeter bin 
directory.
```

I installed the certificate  but still I am getting pop up "see installing the JMeter certificate for HTTPS recording pop up.   and I am unable to fix this issue. Could you please suggest me  how to fix  this issue

Answer (score 4):

Do the following and you'll be through:

Installing the certificate in Firefox 
Choose the following options:

•Tools / Options

•Advanced / Certificates

•View Certificates

•Authorities

•Import ...

•Browse to the JMeter launch directory, and click on the file ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt , press Open

•Click View and check that the certificate details agree with the ones displayed by the JMeter Test Script Recorder

•If OK, select "Trust this CA to identify web sites", and press OK

•Close dialogs by pressing OK as necessary

Comment: Thanks. I tried to import under the tab **Your certificates** rather than the tab **Authorities**, but this gives: _"This personal certificate can’t be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested."_

Answer (score 1):

I got the same you, I worked following pdf, it works ok
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Please find the message below. even after adding certificates in Firefox I am getting this. Internet in my company connects using proxy. I launched `jmeter` using cmd prompt by giving  `jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost`, Have set firefox proxy as `local 8080`, but application is not working. Tried giving same proxy for firefox as well, applciation is working but its not getting recorded in jmeter. have followed steps given in "http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf"

Root CA certificate: ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA created in Jmeter bin directory
You can install it following instruction in component Reference documentation (see Installing Jmeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording paragraph)
Please check the details below when installing the certificate in the browser

> CN=_DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate(Jmeter root CA), OU
>   =USername:M1007788,C=US figerprint(sHA1):d4 ed 5a e9 85 cc ad 83 36 61 68 bf 5d 772f 6c 29 19 05 created: Mon Apr 21 11:05:02 IST 2014

Comment: Message given above is normal message shown by Jmeter while generating the certificate-key pair on start. My suggestion is, **First,** add HTTP Request Defaults in your Testplan and provide your proxy server details. **Second,** use Http4.0 Client in Test script Recorder. **Third,** check port number used with firefox local proxy and bypass option for local sites.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called proxycert.cmd in the extras folder in Jmeter. Import that as a certificate in the browser and it will work