# Cannot Update JMeter ROOT CA Certificate

Tags: jmeter, certificate

Hey I am having an issue with renewing the Certificate (also a very new user to JMeter). I have tried the suggestions from [isue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003639/jmeter-ca-certificate-issue), but none of the solutions worked for me. When I try to add the temporary certificate, I get the message: "This personal certificate can’t be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested." and when I try to use the proxycert.cmd file as a certificate, It says that I need to input a password, I tried with "password" because that's what I saw when I opened the file in an editor, but it didn't work either. I get the message that either the password wrong is, or that the format is wrong or corupt.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You should provide more details like Which browser, Jmeter version, Error screenshot, Browser version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're using incorrect storage, if you want to use JMeter as system-wide certificate to capture traffic not only from browsers but also from 3rd-party applications - you should put it to [Trusted Root Certification Authorities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store)

[image]

If you want to avoid doing this funny exercise each week you can ramp-up that validity time frame by adding the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert):

```
proxy.cert.validity=365
```

which will make JMeter certificates valid for 1 year.

`password` is the default password when you specify your own keystore, when JMeter creates its `proxyserver.jks` it generates a random password each time, theoretically it's possible to get it by attaching debugger session to JMeter process, however this way is not too optimal.

More information:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (pay attention to **HTTPS recording and certificates chapter**)
- [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did both actions and I still cannot add the certificate in the browser (mozilla), same error. I also tried to not add the certificate, but I still get the same error in Jmeter: 2020-09-24 15:38:42,817 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51805]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'dev.api.berrys'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: readHandshakeRecord

Comment: Make sure to perform the import when you're at **Authorities** tab of the Firefox Certificate Manager, if you will still have issues - [clear your Firefox history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox), everything from the beginning of the time. Also be informed that there is an easier way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in that case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates

Comment: thank you very much for the help. adding it to the Authorities tab and not the "Certificates" tab did the trick.