# Recording a test by Jmeter causing errors "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" & "ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED" & "..." JMeter proxy certificate**

Tags: proxy, jmeter, xmlhttprequest, connection, certificate

started recording my test on macOS, with below steps and I am receiving **BELOW RESULTS**

**1.** ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
"If you use a proxy server…
Check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure that the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server: Go to Applications > System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and deselect any proxies that have been selected."

**2.** Went to JMeter result tree
**Response message:**
2.1 Connection reset
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate** 443
2.2 Response message:Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

**JMeter test Steps:**

1. Go to Jmeter and select "Recording" from "Templates"
2. provided paramters due creation
   hostToRecord: [www.tesla.com/en_eu](http://www.tesla.com/en_eu)
   recording file: recordingtesla.xml
   scheme to record: https
3. **STRANGE THING:** Template was created, but going to "User Defined Variables" I see another value provided (another website, which I have used couple of times in my previous tests?)
4. STRANGE THING 2 Going to "Https Test Script Recorder, field domains use the same website, from point 3 (again i HAVE PROVIDED tesla and I can see a previously used website??)
5. HTTP(S) Script recorder and port set to 8888 (saved)
6. User Defined Variables ->
   name: host, value: AGAIN the same website from point 3 &4 (used previously, not putting it for this test)
   name: scheme, value: https
7. RECORDING
8. Going to "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder", pressing start button
   -(Root ca showing up)
   -Target Controller is a Recording controller
   -Grouping is Do not group samplers
   -Went to tesla website (was already opened before I have pressed "Start"
   -I click someting on tesla website and test stopped

**1.** DNS Servers 8.8.8.8

**2.** Proxies settings for all of below (and selected) is localhost: 8888
Web HTTP
Secure Web HTTPS
FTP
SOCKS
Streaming
Gopher

**3**Auto Proxy Discover (without selected localhost & 8888- no fields for this)

Jmeter certyficate should be valid till 2024, I have renewed certyficate, following this instruction  -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043676/cannot-update-jmeter-root-ca-certificate​](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043676/cannot-update-jmeter-root-ca-certificate%E2%80%8B)
BUT IN KEYCHAIN
**Expired: Monday, 26 December 2022 at 10:52:55 Central European Standard Time
marked as trusted **

**4.** am using Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the certificate from the keychain completely
2. Delete `proxyserver.jks` and `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` files in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. [Clear your Chrome browsing history](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) completely
4. When creating the recording test plan from the template use `www.testla.com` without any paths
5. When you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder JMeter will generate new `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file. Default validity is 7 days unless you change [`proxy.cert.validity` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert)
6. Import this certificate into your browser. At this stage I would suggest using [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) instead of Chrome because:

   - Firefox has its own certificates storage and Chrome uses the system one
   - Firefox has its own proxy configuration and Chrome uses the system one
7. It would be also a good idea to exclude other domains than `tesla.com` from recording scope
8. Your recording should be successful

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates

Answer (score 0):

It works for now but, still seems not correct

1. When I set proxy.cert.dynamic_keys false and it finally started recording with some 200 statuses:
   Use dynamic key generation (if supported by JMeter/JVM).
   If false, will revert to using a single key with no certificate.
   Defaults to: true
   BUT SOME TESTS ARE STILL 443 because of cert
   Response message:Connection reset
   **ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**
2. Tried your recommendations also uninstalled and installed JMeter again, cleared and using Firefox for now, cert is valid until 16.01.2023, I have set jmeter.properties file to “#proxy.cert.validity=365” (with hash) and I have checked Firefox -> settings -> cert view and there is 16.01.2023 so looks like again I have to uninstall and install again?
3. Is it correct that when test finished and I want to user browser + internet again I need to go to Firefox settings -> proxy and set back from manual mode (localhost 8888 + https) to no proxy?
   If I stay with manual there is an error:
   “The proxy server is refusing connections

An error occurred during a connection to [www.tesla.com](http://www.tesla.com).

```
Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working.”
```

Answer (score 0):

I were having the same issue and was that I'm connected to a VPN service. I disconnected it and all works perfectly.